# How can I customise javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis to change the hard-coded upper limit of 20 major tick marks

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using the JavaFX NumberAxis component in an application, and it does 99% of what I want. I'm dealing with varying data sets, so the auto-range function is hugely useful.

The auto-range algorithm tries to come up with major tick units that result in less than 20 major tick marks along the axis. And that value of "20" is hard-coded into the source.  I really need this to be less than 20 in some cases, ideally only 10.

So ... how can I modify NumberAxis to do what I want?

The class is final, and the code that makes the autoranging work depends on other code that is further up the hierachy and within the same package (NumberAxis extends ValueAxis, which extends Axis).

I resorted to creating a parallel class hierachy within my source tree, and then creating a custom version of the NumberAxis class. So within my source tree I have

jaxafx.scene.chart.CustomNumberAxis

and then I just copied the original source code from NumberAxis into it and modified the auto-range method.

Unfortunately that raises IllegalAccessExceptions. I'm guessing because the runtime noticed that my code is trying to call package-protected methods that are sitting in jfxtr.jar.

Is there any way round this, or do I just have to copy the autorange algorithm code out into a helper class, and try to detangle it from the chart package dependencies?

Comment: extend your CustomAxis from `ValueAxis<Number>` and just copy the entire `NumberAxis` code while changing what you want.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately the code uses a few methods from superclasses that are package-private, so it's not quite as easy as might be hoped.

Comment: I've done it to make a time axis.  Maybe I deleted package private methods.  I'll have to check.

Answer (score 0):

So I gave up on trying to avoid duplication and just went for the inelegant, brute-force solution.

Created a new package "customchart", and created three new classes CustomAxis, CustomValueAxis and CustomNumberAxis.  Copied in the code from the corresponding JavaFX originals. Fixed up a few class references.  Added the modification I need... and it all seems to work now.

All so I can create an setter method for 1 integer value.